# Extremely slow PDF export in production environment

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, symfony-3.4

I use wkhtmltopdf (knp_snappy) to do PDF exports on symfony 3.4.
In 'dev' environment everything goes perfectly.
In the environment of 'prod' it is another thing, the fast exports are going very well but the voluminous exports are extremely slow.

A large export in 'dev' mode is done in 3 minutes, but is still not finished after 30 minutes in 'prod' mode.

I tried to edit php.ini

> opcache.memory_consumption=256
>
> opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000
>
> opcache.validate_timestamps=0
>
> realpath_cache_size=4096K
>
> realpath_cache_ttl=600

I tried several values, but nothing helps.

The part of my code that is slow is this :

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml($html, 
        $cachePath.$fileNameCreate,
        array( 'header-html'=>$header,
            'footer-html'=>$footer,
            'disable-javascript' => true,
            ));
```

**I did some extra tests, everything works perfectly in dev mode and prod if debug is true. But in prod mode and debug to false it becomes extremely slow again.**

Has anyone ever encountered this type of problem?

Do you have any idea of what might cause this?

Comment: Are there differences between the dev and prod systems? Memory amount, number of processors? Are both dev and prod using the same version of php? What version is used? What is the dev php.ini setup compared to the prod system?

Comment: The dev environment and the prod environment are on the same server. It's the same symfony project.